# Как получить первые четыре элемента из переменной целого типа на СИ?

Tags: c

У меня есть переменная типа int: **int pin = 54654346;**
И я хочу получить из этой переменной первые 4 цифры. Как это реализовать?

Comment: через **pin[1]** не получается.

Comment: это не строка, чтобы так получалось

Comment: Да знаю. Но как именно через переменную это делать?

Comment: Цифр всегда 8 или нет?

Comment: Количество цифр произвольное

Answer (score 3, accepted):

в лоб:

```
const int pin = 54654346;
const std::string text = std::to_string(pin);
const std::string part = text.substr(0, 4);
const int value = std::stoi(part);
```

или на с:

```
const int pin = 54654346;
char text[32];
_itoa_s(pin, text, 32, 10);
text[4] = 0;
const int value = atoi(text);
```

не в лоб, но почти в лоб:

```
const int pin = 54654346;
int number = pin;

int value = 0;

while (number != 0) {
    const int digit = number % 10;
    number /= 10;

    value = value * 10 + digit;
}

value = value % 10000;

int new_value = 0;

while (value != 0) {
    const int digit = value % 10;
    value /= 10;

    new_value = new_value * 10 + digit;
}
```

почти в лоб, но чуть хитрее

```
int variants[10];
int index = 0;

const int pin = 54654346;
int number = pin;

while (number != 0) {
    variants[index++] = number;
    number /= 10;
}

const int value = variants[(index - 4 > 0) ? (index - 4) : 0];
```

вариант через голую математику (правда для положительных чисел, для отрицательных надо `abs` добавить и восстановление знака):

```
const int pin = 54654346;

int power = log10(pin);

const int value = (pin < 10000) ? pin : (pin / pow(10, power - 3));
```

еще один вариант через `while` который не требует дополнительных массивов:

```
const int pin = 54654346;

int value = pin;

while (abs(value) > 10000) value /= 10;
```

Comment: так у вас С++. же

Comment: ок, добавил код еще и на C

Comment: Я благодарен за вашу помощь. Но к сожалению все ваши блоки кода не работают. И вообще вы все замудрили. Вот на питоне я мог просто сделать так: for i in 4: for j in pin: print(pin[j]) А у вас как-то сложно. Это не похоже не решение. Целая функция. Все гораздо проще должно быть.

Comment: Вот почему у вас так много кода для такой простой задачи? Вот почему? Есть же куда более проще!

Comment: исправил пару ошибок (типа не поставил тип переменной) - теперь все способы работают и выдают верный результат, а что касается `на питоне в 1 строчку`, ну добро пожаловать в C++

Comment: касательно `много кода` - если вам нужна именно строка - берите варианты 1 и 2 - их можно записать в 1-2 строчки, если нельзя использовать стоки или вообще хочется все сделать только через арифметику с числами - берите 3 и 4 варианты (и еще раз - не надо сравнивать с питоном)

Comment: Да ладно, я не всерьез эту чушь нес. Спасибо вам огромное. Помогли. Разобрался я в вашем коде и понял что к чему. Последний вариант самый хороший.

Comment: добавил вам еще 1 вариант - через чистую логарифмическую математику

Comment: и еще один вариант - вот этот вам точно понравится - `while` и никаких массивов или промежуточных переменных

Comment: Отлично. Вы сами алгоритмы придумали, или так же узнавали? И раз вы такой профи, не могли бы вы дать какие-нибудь ресурсы с задачками на СИ где можно по практиковаться и закрепить теорию?

Comment: что значит "сами придумали", а как еще можно - в книжках такую мелочь наверное не пишут. на счет ресурса не знаю - вы можете просто посмотреть олимпиадные задачи по программированию

Comment: Ну вот я первый месяц СИ изучаю. Синтаксис изучил, пару программ со своей логикой написал. Там калькулятор, игра в палочки, ToDo. Но вот например вот этот алгоритм придумать не смог. Видимо я тупой для этого программирования ((

Comment: если не собираетесь писать драйвера и т.п., лучше сразу на c++ переходите :-)
так вы задачу просто придумайте, а под нее уже и алгоритмы можно будет учить

Comment: Мне для реверса чистый С нужен.